# Color coding cell error containing specific values

Tags: python, excel, colors, openpyxl, cell

I'm currently stuck when it comes to color coding cells with specific values containing =="PPI". I'm using openpyxl to save an excel sheet that will state the color code RedFill if these cells in column B contain the value "PPI". I have a feeling I'm missing something specific in my code.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, Alignment, Border, Side, PatternFill



filename='DB_1.xlsx'

workbook = load_workbook(filename='DB_1.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active

bold_font = Font(bold=True)
big_blue_text = Font(color="000066CC", size=11)
center_aligned_text = Alignment(horizontal="center")
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF0000',end_color='FFFF0000',fill_type='solid')

cell_1= sheet["G1"]
cell_1

cell_1.value = " Notes "
cell_1.value

cell_2 = sheet["A1"]
cell_2

cell_2.value = " Primary Key"
cell_2.value

sheet.auto_filter.ref = "A1:G1"

for c in sheet["A1:G1"][0]:
    c.font = bold_font
    
for a in sheet["A1:G1"][0]: 
    a.font = big_blue_text
    
for b in sheet["A1:G1"][0]:
    b.alignment = center_aligned_text
    
    
for d in sheet["B:B"]:
    if d == "PPI": 
        d.PatternFill = RedFill
```

More specifically:

```
for d in sheet["B:B"]:
    if d == "PPI": 
        d.PatternFill = RedFill
```

Below are the samples data that I need to color code that contains "PPI":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3DYn.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are few changes required...

1. The `d == "PPI"` will return false as it is not searching for a
   pattern. You need to search for the substring using something like
   `if "PPI" in d.value`
2. If true, you need to use `d.fill = redFill`, not d.PatternFill
3. If not already doing it, do save the file

I was able to make this work updating the code like this. Hope this helps.

```
for d in sheet["B:B"]:
    if "PPI" in d.value: 
        d.fill = redFill
        
workbook.save('new.xlsx') ## Or whatever name you want the updated file to be in
```